# How to register the same instance(= singleton) for 2 interfaces within a prism IContainerRegistry

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I've a `Prism` app, with `Unity` to make dependency injection.

I've one class that has the following inheritance:

```
ISomeService --> ISomeMoreSpecializedService --> SomeMoreSpecializedService
```

- `ISomeService` is used in some non-application-specific module.
- `ISomeMoreSpecializedService` is extending this previous interface, adding some application-specific concept
- `SomeMoreSpecializedService`  is the only implementation that should be used in a specific software
- (There is also an abstract implementation of ISomeService)

My specialized service looks like this:

```
public class SomeMoreSpecializedService : SomeService, ISomeMoreSpecializedService
{
    public SomeMoreSpecializedService(ISomeDependency dependency){
    }
}
```

I'm in a Prism Module:

```
public class MyModule : IModule
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISomeService, SomeMoreSpecializedService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISomeMoreSpecializedService, SomeMoreSpecializedService>();
    }

    public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
    {
    }
}
```

But my issue is that I receive then 2 different singleton. How should I do this?

Before I was building a `new SomeMoreSpecializedService()`, and then doing `RegisterInstance`. This worked until now, but now I've some dependency to inject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Unity, you do

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<FactoryController>();
containerRegistry.Register<IFactoryController, FactoryController>();
containerRegistry.Register<IFactoryToken, FactoryController>();
```

i.e. a `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` for the type without any interfaces and then attach the type to two interfaces without specified lifetime manager.

Unfortunately, the behavior of `IContainerRegistry.Register` and `IContainerRegistry.RegisterSingleton` is mostly undefined and they just leak the behavior of the underlying container. So this will work, unless Unity changes its behavior (which it did in the past) or you switch to another container.

Comment: It's a shame that this is not defined by Unity, but I'm quite happy I found a workaround, thank you very much!

Comment: For Unity, it's defined, but e.g. DryIOC defines different behavior. The problem's that Prism puts an abstraction layer on top of these _without_ defining the behavior to be expected by users of the abstraction.